# Excel VBA copy template worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm VBA noobs and in need to finish my assignment.

I would like to copy a template worksheets into and copy some cell automatically to it.
Here's what I get from webs, and I'm stuck now..

```
Sub CopyTemplate()
    Dim myCell As Range, MyRange As Range, Orange As Range
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Isolation Section").Range("B24")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))
    Set Orange = Sheets("Isolation Section").Range("D24")
    Set Orange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each myCell In MyRange
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        With myCell
            ActiveSheet.Name = .Value
            ActiveSheet.Range("A13").Value = .Value
            ActiveSheet.Range("E13").Value = Orange.Value
            .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=myCell, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
               "'" & .Text & "'!B24", TextToDisplay:=.Text
        End With
    Next myCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have a template sheet called *Template*.
 I create a copy of *Template* sheet and name it after each row from *Isolation Section* (so a loop). 
 Then place the cell data row **B24** in cell 
**A13** of the sheet. 
But how about the cell data row **D24** from *Isolation Section* copied to each sheets in new worksheets cell **E13**?

**Image:**

[image: Sample Image]

Sorry if my English is bad..

Comment: Your code doesn't add up. First, you need to remove copying the *Template worksheet* in your loop. Second, you need to clarify what changes you need to make in the newly copied *Template worksheet*. Clarify your question and specifically point out what's not working. As is now, it is unclear.

Comment: In your edit, you never set the variable `Orange`. Also I think it is worth adding a screen shot or illustration of what you want to achieve.

Comment: i cannot add the screen shot, my reputation not enough.. T.T

Comment: Just post the link and I'll do it for you. Just upload it in a free image hosting website like this one: [i.imgur.com](http://i.imgur.com)

Comment: http://imgur.com/WCmC7i1 , i just want Description row to automatically copied to green highlight

Comment: Ok. That's more like it. So everything is working fine except adding the description? Or what else is not working?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine except adding the description, and because I'm not understand VBA or macro, I'm foolishly added `Orange , hehe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
For Each mycell In MyRange
    Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = mycell
        .Range("A1").Value = mycell.value
        .Range("E1").Value = mycell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End With
    mycell.Parent.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=myCell, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'" & mycell.Text & "'!B24", TextToDisplay:=mycell.Text
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description isn't very clear, but the easiest way to resolve your issue would be to just use macro recorder and copy and paste the code.

Here's microsoft's site on how to create/delete one: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010342374.aspx

I create macros sometimes and as long as you know something about coding, you can just glue together a couple of macro recordings and have a working macro... that's actually standardised. Good luck.